# multinom() in R: can I use for prediction on other dataset?

Tags: r, probability, logistic-regression, predict, multinomial

I have run a multinom() model, then how can I use these model on other dataset? For example I want to fit this model to another dataset and generate predicted probabilities for that dataset, like mnrval() did in Matlab--- it takes the model estimated by mnrfit() and apply it to outside data to generate predicted probability. I'm currently constrained with R so can't use Matlab. Thanks.

Comment: You posted several question on multinom. Did you checkout the answers (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34731460/how-does-multinom-treat-na-values-by-default) e.g. using the predict which would have lead you to the answer for this question.

Comment: If this was not a duplicate of the earlier question with an apparently on-target answer (in R), then you need to post a dataset and your efforts at coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See example in `?multinom`:

```
mymultinommodel <- multinom(low ~ ., bwt)
predict(mymultinommodel,new.data=newdata)
```

To get probabilities instead of predicted class:

```
predict(mymultinommodel,new.data=newdata, type="probs")
```

Comment: but this is not giving me probabilities but rather it gives me one category for each obs. For example if my categories are cat1, cat2, cat3, then if I use predict() it's giving me a vector like "cat1 cat3 cat2 cat1". This is not the probabilities I want. What I want is something similar to what fitted() function returns (i.e. probabilities for each category),  but using another dataset. Thanks.

Comment: I think it should be newdata instead of new.data, but it worked. Thanks.